# Something wrong with quickblox integration

Tags: java, android, api, exception, quickblox

Why does this happen:

> Login Failed com.quickblox.core.exception.QBResponseException: 
>                                                                   Something wrong with your Account Key. Please check it in QuickBlox Admin Panel

Comment: Have you added you account key to the credentials in your app code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably it's something wrong with your AccountKey or you did not set it:

```
QBSettings.getInstance().setAccountKey(ACCOUNT_KEY);
```

Go to [QuickBlox Dashboard](https://admin.quickblox.com/account) and copy the AccountKey value.

Read more [here.](https://quickblox.com/developers/Android#Initialize_framework)

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue.
I Already set 
`QBSettings.getInstance().setAccountKey(Constants.ACCOUNT_KEY);`

But in Example, there were code to set proxy.

```
Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("10.30.30.1", 3128));
QBHttpConnectionConfig.setProxy(proxy);
```

Just comment or remove this proxy code. and it works ok.

Comment: Thanks alot, you saved my day.

Comment: @UmairIqbal Happy coding :-)